# Slow speed with stepping motor

Tags: motor, servo, stepper

I am currently working on a project where I need a stepping motor and a servo running at the same time, the servo turns fine and the speed is ok, but the stepping motors speed is very slow and as a result it is loud. I tried the code for the stepping motor on its own and it runs faster, but when it is ran with the servo it is slow. I have follwed a few tutorials to get this to the stage it is at currently, I have removed any delays that i could find which did help a little, but it is still not enough.

The servo is powered from the arduino and the stepping motor is powered by a 12v plug. I am just not sure if there is something within this code that is causing it to slow down? Thank you for you time! The code that it is running slow from is here:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;

// Configurable Variables
int MaxServoTurn = 20;

// Spooky Variables
int pos = 0;
int customDelay;
int customDelayMapped;
const int pin_LED = 10;
const int pin_switch = 8;
const int stepPin = 3;
const int dirPin = 4;
boolean oldSwitchState = LOW;
boolean newSwitchState1 = LOW;
boolean newSwitchState2 = LOW;
boolean newSwitchState3 = LOW;
unsigned long timeNow = 0;
unsigned long timePrev = 0;
unsigned int timeWait = 100;
boolean flashingLEDisON = false;
boolean LEDstatus = LOW;
boolean keyPressed = false;
boolean buttonToggle = false;


// Setup only, call functions in here
void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  //Sets the two pins as Outputs
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
  //Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
  digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(pin_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin_LED, LOW);
  pinMode(pin_switch, INPUT);
}

// This is the main controller for the application
void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= MaxServoTurn; pos += 1) {
    buttonLoop();
    if (buttonToggle == true) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      setupPotentiometer();
    }
  }
  for (pos = MaxServoTurn; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
    buttonLoop();
    if (buttonToggle == true) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      setupPotentiometer();
    }
  }
}

void buttonLoop() {
  newSwitchState1 = digitalRead(pin_switch);
  newSwitchState2 = digitalRead(pin_switch);

  newSwitchState3 = digitalRead(pin_switch);

  if (  (newSwitchState1 == newSwitchState2) && (newSwitchState1 == newSwitchState3) )
  {
    if ( newSwitchState1 != oldSwitchState )
    {
      if ( newSwitchState1 == HIGH ) {
        keyPressed = true;
        buttonToggle = true;
      } else {
        keyPressed =  false;
        buttonToggle = false;
      }
      oldSwitchState = newSwitchState1;
    }
  }


  if ( keyPressed )
  {
    // turn on or turn off the blinking LED
    if ( flashingLEDisON == false)
    {
      flashingLEDisON = true;
    }
    else
    {
      flashingLEDisON = false;
      // the LED may be on so to be safe we turn it off. If you wished you could check LEDstatus
      LEDstatus = LOW;  digitalWrite(pin_LED, LEDstatus);
    }
    keyPressed = false;
  }

  // if the blinking LED is on. See if it is time to blink it
  if ( flashingLEDisON == true )
  {
    timeNow = millis();
    if (timeNow - timePrev >= timeWait )
    {
      timePrev = timeNow;
      if (LEDstatus == LOW) {
        LEDstatus = HIGH;
      } else {
        LEDstatus = LOW;
      }
      digitalWrite(pin_LED, LEDstatus);
    }
  }
}

void setupPotentiometer() {
  customDelayMapped = speedUp(); // Gets custom delay values from the custom speedUp function
  // Makes pules with custom delay, depending on the Potentiometer, from which the speed of the motor depends
  digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(customDelayMapped);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(customDelayMapped);
}

// Function for reading the Potentiometer
int speedUp() {
  int customDelay = analogRead(A0); // Reads the potentiometer
  int newCustom = map(customDelay, 0, 1023, 300, 4000); // Convrests the read values of the potentiometer from 0 to 1023 into desireded delay values (300 to 4000)
  return newCustom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a project where I needed to run two steppers at the same time as they were moving a heavy load and were moving the same piece.

While a servo is going to move the desired spot, a stepper will not.

In the process of setting up the stepper you designated steps per rev and amount of steps to take at a time.

The stepper is only going to move the "amount of steps" at a time for each run of the code. I ran into a similar  problem and I had to put in a 2ms delay after the servo run command to make the motors run smoother and faster, other wise it sounded like a bunch of gears gnashing and skipping.  These steppers were facing each other that is why they move opposite directions.

```cpp
if (down==true){
  TLstep.step(-step1);
  TRstep.step(step1);
  delay(2);
}
```

I know it been a year since this was looked at. Hope you got your issue figured out.

Answer (score 0):

A stepper motor requires that you send pulsed control signals to it for each step. If you want it to run at a given number of steps/second, you have to send the controlling pulses at the correct time intervals.

If you have delays in your code, it will slow down the timing of the control pulses, and slow down your steppers. You need to rewrite your code to use millis() to calculate the timing of your control signals instead of using `delay()` or `delayMicroseconds()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply Duncan, do I just change the two `delayMicroseconds(customDelayMapped);` to `millis()` as you mentioned? I’m pretty new to the arduino so I’m sorry if I’m misunderstanding this!

Comment: no, you need to refactor your code to keep track of elapsed time and change states when the desired time interval has passed. Do a search on "Arduino Blink Without Delay" and study the sketches you find. It won't be a copy/paste change but rather a refactoring of your code. You might be able to find sample code for steppers and servos that doesn't use delays, which would make your job easier.